# Can't filter using backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to filter a column using backing bean function.

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" 
             var="car" 
             value="#{manageAllCoursesBean.courses}"
             filteredValue="#{manageAllCoursesBean.filteredCourse1}"> 

    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                         onkeyup="PF('carsTable1').filter()" 
                         style="width:250px" 
                         placeholder="Entrer un mot clé"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Name"
              filterBy="#{car.name}"
              sortBy="#{car.name}"
              style="color: #400040; font-size: 10px; width: 150px; text-align:center">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Teacher"
              filteredBy="#{manageAllCoursesBean.findTeacherByIdCourse(car.id)}"
              sortBy="#{manageAllCoursesBean.findTeacherByIdCourse(car.id)}"
              style="color: #400040; font-size: 10px; width: 175px; text-align:center">
        <h:outputText value="#{manageAllCoursesBean.findTeacherByIdCourse(car.id)}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

the backing bean method is:

```
public String findTeacherByIdCourse(String courseId) throws IOException
{
    return serviceManager.findTeacherByCourseId(courseId);
}
```

the filter with **Name** is working as well.
However, is not the case with **Teacher**.

Have you please any idea about solving that ?.
Big thanks.

Comment: Hello Sir @Kukeltje, you're right. I changed the tags. I meant that - As explained on PrimeFaces showcase - the filter gives the desired resultes with `filterBy="#{car.name}"` . However can't work with `filteredBy="#{manageAllCoursesBean.findTeacherByIdCourse(car.id)}"`

Comment: Why do you expect the `filteredBy="#{manageAllCoursesBean.findTeacherByIdCourse(car.id)}"` to work? Where did you read it should? And _"can't work"_ is not really a good description a developer would give... is the method called? And there still is no version info, not a [mcve] not any indication what you tried searching/reading etc... Please improve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on **Primefaces showcase**, there's no way to use managed bean method with `filterBy` under `p:column`.

I proposed that solution: 
You can convert your entity `Course` to a `courseModel` and then add `teachers` as a list of strings.

then in your managed bean will be :

```
List<CourrierModel> lacmss = new ArrayList<CourrierModel>();
DataModel allDatasAssociatedCE = new ListDataModel();

//...

allDatasAssociatedCE.setWrappedData(lacmes);
for(Course c: courses)
{
   CourseModel cme = new CourseModel();
   cme.setCourse(c);
   cme.setTeachers(findTeacherByIdCourse(c));
   lacmss.add(cme);
}
```

HTH.